# SDK manager issue in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to edit `ADB` check box,but there is not ADB check box in "`SDK manager > Build,Execution,Deployment > Debugger`". Why is it? and how does it appear?
Here u can understand better by viewing image below.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by ADB checkbox, can you be more specific? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: tell your android studio version too.

Comment: sorry,I mean the check box named "Use libsub backend".I want to achieve installing "hello world" program,but there is a comment "Installation failed due to :null".

Comment: version is 3.5.

Comment: Posting a screenshot might be helpful to explain the problem here

Comment: ok.I appended the link.

Comment: hey did u follow answer below?

Comment: yeah,I appreciate your kind responce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, you want to install ADB.

```
 Tools>SDK Manager>Plugins.
```

Input adb , then install it(My Android Studio version is 3.5).

Answer (score 0):

According to above comment `"Installation failed due to :null"` this is my suggestion to do.

- Open **Run/Debug Configuration dialog**
- Edit **Your app > General > Installation Options > Install Flags**.
- ***add install flags `-r` `-t`***  as [`-r` means "replace existing
  application" & `-t` means "allow test packages"].

This flags means `adb install -r -t apkpath`.

[image]

Comment: thanks!I don't know what made it to be successful,anyway it went well!